# Ruby Map Complex Nested JSON to my own Ruby Class?

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

I need to be able to map a complex nested json from API result to my own custom class representation. Also need to be able to edit the data and send it back to API as json.

Tried searching on this previously. Could only find how to map to `OpenStruct`.

In other languages like C# I can do something like this:

```
public class SomeViewModel
        {
public SomeViewModel(){
            A = new AViewModel();
            B = new BViewModel();
            Cs = new List<C>();
        }

        public string D {get; set;}
}
```

Where A, B, and C are complex types (can contain other properties of other class types, arrays of class types, etc). I could then use a few libraries to map a JSON request to `SomeViewModel` and be able to access all properties and methods. Looking to do the same in Ruby.

My JSON contains many objects and array of objects. Some of the situations are an object with arrays of objects (arrays of objects can also contain arrays of objects) and nested arrays (which can also contain objects and arrays of objects). Now I'm aware that I could use the hash syntax notation but then I'd have to map each k-v pair individually. I'm sure there is a more DRY-er way in Ruby?

Let's say here is a JSON snippet (greatly reduced as the actual JSON is WAY too large and can't use real data anyway):

```
"SomeViewModel": {
    "Bank": {
        "ID": 585263,
        "BankName": "First Bank of CA",
        "Drawer": null,
        "LockDate": "2020-02-24T08:45:13.507",
        "BankerPartyID": "9EE7AE0A-4001",
        "BankNumber": 4090466,
        "BusinessPolicyID": 21,
        "VersionNumber": "b5e8f11d-38cc-4861-9701-78e61a8f47d9",
        "RepositoryName": null,
        "IsBankToConvert": false,
        "CreatedBy": null,
        "ServerRootPath": null,
        "SubmissionNumber": null,
        "ReasonId": null,
        "BankNotes": [], # Blank but coul also be an array of objects
    },
    "BankRequest": {
        "BankHolder": null,
        "BankTeam": null,
        "PrimaryBanker": null,
    },
    "Customers": [{
            "Name": "Dave"
            "Phone": "555-555-5555"
        }, {
            "Name": "Bob"
            "Phone": "555-555-5555"
        }
    ],
    "CurrentBankContract": {
        "BankHolder": {
            "BankHolderID": 1303164,
            "SubscribingBankers": [{
                    "ElementGUID": "hihrwigohw-923489709724-jkflnanf3",
                    "ContractBankID": 1257638,
                }, {
                    "ElementGUID": "4545ojoj-923489709724-jkflnanf3",
                    "ContractBankID": 1257456,
                }
            ],
            "BankNew": false,
            "BankID": 585263,
        },
        "BankerTeam": {
            "ContractBankerTeamMemberID": 5432605,
            "Type": 1,
            "SubscribingBanker": {
                "ElementGUID": "45363-gsgsfdr-34525",
                "ContractBankComponentID": 1257638,
            },
            "BankID": 585263,
        }
    }
}
```

I would need to map `SomeViewModel` and all of its contents. Now for an attribute like `BankNotes`, while it is an attribute to the `Bank` class it really is an array of type `BankNote`. So instead of a class named BankNotes I would have a class called BankNote and looking to map that part of it so that `BankNotes` can be an array of type `BankNote` and have access to all methods in the `BankNote` class. Anyway to map complex JSON to my own Ruby class?

Comment: You'll need to interpret the structure at each level accordingly. There's no built-in way to do this. It could be as easy as `@customers = args["Customers"].map { |c| Customer.new(c) }` and so on within an `initialize(args)`.

Comment: Might be worth looking into GraphQL parsers - I know only a little bit about it, so could be barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you, your goal is parse json to object?

Here's your json(edited):

```js
{
    "Bank": {
        "ID": 585263,
        "BankName": "First Bank of CA",
        "Drawer": null,
        "LockDate": "2020-02-24T08:45:13.507",
        "BankerPartyID": "9EE7AE0A-4001",
        "BankNumber": 4090466,
        "BusinessPolicyID": 21,
        "VersionNumber": "b5e8f11d-38cc-4861-9701-78e61a8f47d9",
        "RepositoryName": null,
        "IsBankToConvert": false,
        "CreatedBy": null,
        "ServerRootPath": null,
        "SubmissionNumber": null,
        "ReasonId": null,
        "BankNotes": []
    },
    "BankRequest": {
        "BankHolder": "Hello, I'm bankholder from JSON!",
        "BankTeam": null,
        "PrimaryBanker": null
    },
    "Customers": [{
        "Name": "Dave",
        "Phone": "555-555-5555"
    }, {
        "Name": "Bob",
        "Phone": "555-555-5555"
    }],
    "CurrentBankContract": {
        "BankHolder": {
            "BankHolderID": 1303164,
            "SubscribingBankers": [{
                "ElementGUID": "hihrwigohw-923489709724-jkflnanf3",
                "ContractBankID": 1257638
            }, {
                "ElementGUID": "4545ojoj-923489709724-jkflnanf3",
                "ContractBankID": 1257456
            }],
            "BankNew": false,
            "BankID": 585263
        },
        "BankerTeam": {
            "ContractBankerTeamMemberID": 5432605,
            "Type": 1,
            "SubscribingBanker": {
                "ElementGUID": "45363-gsgsfdr-34525",
                "ContractBankComponentID": 1257638
            },
            "BankID": 585263
        }
    }
}
```

Code that parses JSON to object:

```rb
require "json"
require "hashie"

file = File.read("example.json")
hash = JSON.parse(file, object_class: OpenStruct)
json_object = Hashie::Mash.new hash
json_object.BankRequest.BankHolder #=> "Hello, I'm bankholder from JSON!"
```

What i did here:

1. Readed item by File class
2. Parsed JSON to OpenStruct and
3. Created object from hash
4. Outputed value

As you can see - json_object is a Class with self methods.
Every key is self method that can contain another self methods e.t.c

Comment: Hi.Thanks. Also the other part of my question. If my Class has some other methods lets say simple method `def bank_holder_id @BankHolderID end`. In this case `BankHolderID` is attribute in `BankHolder` class and `bank_holder_id` is an actual method on `BankHolder`. For every 'class' in the JSON I have created a ruby class for it. Some classes have some methods on it though like I described. With your solution would I have access to call those methods?

Comment: @Bmoe Hi. In Ruby you can put class inside module, but you can not put class inside another class. Ruby have inheritance (class < super_class). So if you have class inside class it will not work. Also, if you have array of hashes in JSON you need to use index.I added gist, so you can see what to do with array: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GosuGod/5760ed5fafb1c290c4ec8b8edf391069/raw/877e40674006d217b81c2d6060f1b2bedda1d227/Example%2520json%2520with%2520two%2520hashes